# Check foreach iframe for ClassName and create new iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm absolut new to javascript and just need a quick & dirty solution.

My goal is to check each loaded iframe for a specific ClassName and create either a new iframe or a popup with a url associated to the previously checked iframe. This should be done every few seconds.

My code looks like this and I don't get any errors so far.
I would be very glad, if you could point me in the right direction.

```
var Kunden = ["x", "y", "z", "w"];
var URLs =["xlink", "ylink", "zlink", "wlink"];

Kunden.forEach(loading_iframe)

function loading_iframe(item, index){
    
    document.querySelector(item).addEventListener("load", (event) => {
     var Error = document.getElementsByClassName("sensorlinkred");
     if (Error != undefined){
        prepareFrame.call(URLs);
     
}else{
    alert('Do no Exists');
    }
})

function prepareFrame(URLs) {
        var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
        ifrm.setAttribute("src", URLs);
        ifrm.style.width = "840px";
        ifrm.style.height = "160px";
        document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Maybe I should mention that the values in "var Kunden" are the iframe IDs which should be checked.

Comment: You stated your goal, and provided the code you have, but you forgot to add a question. What is that question? Is there anything not working with the code you posted? If so, what is not working?

Comment: Indeed. Sorry. Currently it will not create another iframe via the function prepareFrame. But I don't know if I did the function calls properly or if there are any errors. So I guess I just wanted some advice to find a suitable solution for my goal.

Comment: One thing I can see right now: `Kunden` contains strings such as `"x"`. Then, in `loading_frame`, you do `document.querySelector(item)`, where `item` is `"x"`. But it's not a valid CSS selector. Did you mean `document.getElementById(item)`? Also, I think `prepareIframe.call(URLs)` shoud just be `prepareFrame(URLs)` (this is not how `.call` is used)

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion works like a charm. But I noticed another problem: Currently it should appear two addional iframes, but four iframes were created. I see that I didn't forwarded the index parameter to the function prepareFrame. What is the cleanest  solution for this. I mean how can I match the items from "Kunden" and "URLs" easily. Goal is when in the `function loading_iframe` for example the iframe item x contains the Class "sensorlinkred", the `function prepareFrame`should generate an iframe with xlink.

Comment: I'm sorry, you've lost me here  Could you update your question with a clear example? It's hard to understand clearly, just from a long comment